# Use row 1 column ith as output filename awk

Tags: awk, command-line

I'm a very recent command line user thus I'm requiring some help to split a text file by columns using awk. The difficulty for me is that I want the ith filename to be the text from the 1st row of the ith column.

This is what I had in mind:

```
awk '{for(i = 2; i <= NF; i++){name= ??FNR == 1 $i?? ;print $1, $i > name}}' myfile.txt
```

But I don't know how to set the name variable...

Input: myfile.txt

```
'ID'    'sample_1' 'sample_2' ...
'id_1'      1            2    ...
'id_2'      2            3    ...
```

Excpected output:

sample_1.txt:

```
'ID'    'sample_1'
'id_1'      1      
'id_2'      2
```

sample_2.txt:

```
'ID'    'sample_2'
'id_1'      2      
'id_2'      3
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing what you tried. Please add samples for input and expected output too in your post and do let us know then.

Comment: Indeed, what is *the ith filename* in this context? Awk reads a file at a time and its name is in the `FILENAME` variable, but this does not seem to be what you are asking about.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post with examples of input/output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep column headers in an array.

```
awk 'NR==1 {
    for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) {
        fnames[i] = gensub(/\x27/, "", "g", $i) 
        print $1, $i > fnames[i] ".txt"
    }
    next
}
{
    for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i)
        print $1, "\x27" $i "\x27" > fnames[i] ".txt"
}' myfile.txt
```

- `\x27` is single quote in hex-escaped form
- `gensub(/\x27/, "", "g", $i)` removes single quotes from column headers to name output files as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this awk :

```
awk -F'\t' '                              # tab as field separator
{
  for ( i = 2 ; i <= NF ; i++ ) {         # for each record loop from field 2 to last field
    if ( NR == 1 ) {                      # if first record
      a[i] = $i                           # keep each field in array a
      gsub ( /^'\''|'\''$/ , "" , a[i] )  # remove quote at start and end in array a
      }
    print $1 FS $i > a[i]".txt"           # print needed field in corresponding file
  }
}' myfile.txt
```